# How to create simple fractional number sequence?

Tags: r

I need a sequence, converted to strings, of simple fractional numbers, as in

```
"72.05", "71.95", "71.85", ...
```

Why is it that R uses such bizarre internal representations that you get the below results? - Kind of a throw-back to the very early days of pocket calculators, or am I missing something important on the way R does arithmetic?

```
paste(seq(72.05, -53.95, by = -0.1))[621:626]
```

results in very unexpected

```
"10.05" "9.95" "9.84999999999999" "9.74999999999999" "9.64999999999999" "9.55"
```

(I can certainly manually correct this particular output, however I start to doubt internal precisions of R in a very fundamental way...)

(R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14), 64bit, on Windows)

Comment: I would guess [this is somewhat related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal), which isn't really R specific, [just floating points is general](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)

Comment: [Another relevant thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Rounding-error-in-seq-td904967.html)